# Love is a chore

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, rhyme, poetry

There's a match in my pocket
And an ace up my sleeve
Yet I'm no magician
That you can conceive

I'm admired in New York
London and more
Yet I am no God
And love is a chore

You can set me on grass
Or mould me with clay
Yet all ties are broken
At the end of the day

What am I?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are:

> Tennis

There's a match in my pocket / And an ace up my sleeve
Yet I'm no magician / That you can conceive

> 'match' and 'ace' are both common tennis terms

I'm admired in New York /London and more
Yet I am no God / And love is a chore

> Major tennis tournaments occur in both cities.  'Love' is another tennis term, meaning 'no score,' which makes winning a game a bit of a chore.

You can set me on grass /Or mould me with clay
Yet all ties are broken/ At the end of the day

> Tennis is played either on grass or clay.  No tennis match ends in a tie.  Furthermore, no game or set can end in a tie, all have rules for tiebreakers such as advantage, etc.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why love is a chore, and "all ties are broken"?

Comment: Added a bit more explanation

Comment: Great job - "set" is also a minor clue :)